# How to properly select nth element from the list of elements by CSS selector

Tags: java, html, css, selenium

I'm new to Selenium and Java and I'm trying to select the `nth` element by CSS selector.

I want to get desired values from the code below and save them for further use. I have successfully used XPATH that looks like this

`//*[@class='search-result__advert' and not(@id)][i]` (i = nth element)

I'm trying to practice getting the values by CSS selector and I came up with this (doesn't work as expected)

`.search-result__advert:not([id]):not([data-ad-show]):nth-child(i)` (I've also tried `:nth-of-type(i)`)

What I expect for `i=3`:
The third element that has no **id** attribute and no **data-ad-show** attribute is selected, the value would be **Desired value 3**.

Instead I get `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .search-result__advert:not([id]):not([data-ad-show]):nth-child(3)` It works fine for i=1, i=2, i=5.

```html
<ul class="search-result list-unstyled">

    <li class="search-result__advert">
        <div class="grid grid--rev">
            <p>Desired value 1</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    
    <li class="search-result__advert">
        <div class="grid grid--rev">
            <p>Desired value 2</p>
        </div>
    </li>      

    <li class="search-result__advert" id="signUpWrapper">
        <div id="signUpSavedSearch" class="grid">
            <p>Advertisment 1</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="search-result__advert hidden" data-ad-show="ad_list_middle">
        <div class="ad" id="ad_list_middle">
            <p>Advertisment 2</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="search-result__advert">
        <div class="grid grid--rev">
            <p>Desired value 3</p>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="search-result__advert">
        <div class="grid grid--rev">
            <p>etc. etc.</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the CSS selector

```
ul.search-result div.grid--rev
```

This filters out all the ads. Now you can use code to iterate through the list instead of having to rely on iterating using the locator.

Comment: I already have the code writen in certain way for xpath so I won't change it but next time I will use the solution you propose as it seems most elegant to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent css selector would be :

```
li.search-result__advert:not(id):nth-last-child(2)
```

For better understanding if you apply `nth-child` you can take a look at the below :

```
:nth-child(n)   p:nth-child(2)  Selects every <p> element that is the second child of its parent
```

Read more about CSS_SELECTOR [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but if I do `li.search-result__advert:nth-child(3)` it selects the **Advertisment 1** which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @leafHM : Updated the locator, please check again.

Comment: thanks, this does the job by selecting **Desired value 3**. How can I change the selector to work for other Desired values too? I would like to select **Desired value 1** and **Desired value 2** by using i like i=1 => first value, i=2 => second value etc.

Comment: if you pay attention we are using `nth-last-child` so if you want to select `Desired value 1 ` you can probably use this `li.search-result__advert:not(id):nth-last-child(6)` , for `Desired value 2` use `li.search-result__advert:not(id):nth-last-child(5)`

Comment: Yes, I see. Now, if I use the selector `li.search-result__advert:not(id):nth-last-child(2)` and change the number, it still selects the ads though. So for example, if I use `li.search-result__advert:not(id):nth-last-child(4)` the **Advertisment 1** is selected. Which seems odd as the `<li>` has `id` attribute. To visualize it, I use SelectorGadget for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the correct css selector will be

```
.search-result__advert:not(id):not(data-ad-show):nth-last-child(i)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but if I do this, it still selects the advertisment for some reason. Also it selects the elements from the bottom.